# Clear parent relationship, but keep animation

Tags: animation, objects, parent

By hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> in the 3D View Window, I can clear the parent relationship.

But then I lose the animation endowed to my object by the parent object.  How can I clear an object's parent, but keep the same animation?

Answer (score 12):

Select the child object, and in the 3D View header, go to `Object` > `Animation` > `Bake Action`.

In the pop-up dialogue, enable `Clear Parents`, then hit `OK`.

Comment: I have a little problem...
When i click "ok" the object go smaller... can you help me please ?
Good bye :)

Comment: @Kingabin Try applying scale before `Ctrl + A`

Answer (score 3):

From *Object > Animation > Bake Action* :

- If you have parent child animation turn on *Visual Keying* and *Clear Parents*
- If you have constraint animation turn on *Visual Keying* and *Clear Constraints*